# Can Compare the date and time in While Loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have done something like this for my condition, I need to compare it like this, but my script is keep execute and never end, did I missed out something?

Can someone help me on this?

Starting at @DisplayStartTime = '11:00', and it will increase overtime.

```
Declare @nextStartTime nvarchar(30)
        set @nextStartTime = @DisplayStartTime

        WHILE (CONVERT(DateTime, '2015-04-17' @nextStartTime ) <= CONVERT(DateTime, '2015-04-18 23:00:00'))

        begin

            set @DisplayStartTime = @nextStartTime
            select @nextStartTime = ltrim(right(convert(varchar(100), DATEADD(minute, @Frequency, @nextStartTime)),8))


            insert into #ActualTimeSlot
            select @Parameter,@DisplayStartTime ,@nextStartTime,LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),DATEADD(minute,convert(int,@Tolerance),@nextStartTime),100),8))) as CodeEndTime,@Frequency,@Tolerance 


            set @intFlag +=1
        end
```

Comment: Well, my best guess would be that your script will keep running because the WHILE condition is always true. `2015-04-17 11:00PM` will always and forever be smaller then '2015-04-18 7:00PM'. What is it you are trying to accomplish? Got more code to share with us?

Comment: not really, I need to insert into another table.so I need to make it to run in this condition.

Comment: But, again, the `WHILE` condition is meaningless, it will always be true thus run forever. It's the same as saying `WHILE (1 < 2)`. Are you trying to copy over rows which fall below a certain date or within a date range? It would help a great deal if you could update your question with a better description of the problem you are trying to solve. What are you trying to do in SQL?

Comment: Your condition is *essentially* the same as  `WHILE (17 < 18)`.

Comment: I have updated the questions. So basically that's what I want, the starting time will keep on increase until it reach the '2015-04-18 23:00:00'

Comment: With what you have, the time in the while condition will **NOT** keep increasing. You coded a constant there. Thus, the loop continues forever.

Comment: do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your objective? What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: okay..my actual problem is, I want to keep on increase the time within 24 hours, basically if it start at 2015-01-01 11:00PM I would expect it to stop counting/adding time when it reach 2015-01-02 11:00PM. The time I meant if start at 2015-01-01 11:00PM + 2 hours = 2015-01-01 1:00AM , an so on.

Comment: 1 AM + 2 Hours=3AM , and 3 AM + 2 hours = 5AM  and it keeps on going until it reach 2015-01-012 11:00PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to loop every two hours until 24 hrs has passed from the start time, correct?  the below will do that utilizing DATEADD function.  all you need to do now is plug in your logic.

```
declare @starttime datetime = '1/1/2015 11:00 PM'
declare @endtime datetime = DATEADD(d, 1, @starttime)

while @starttime <= @endtime
begin
select @starttime
set @starttime = DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @starttime)
end
```

Comment: this is crazy, but it works like crazy. you are right I need to work with logic now.thank you so much!